# Sending E-mails on XAMPP

Tags: php, email, xampp, sendmail.exe

first off I want to assure you that I have looked this up.  I have been at this all day and have read multiple articles both here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.  I have tried multiple settings/configurations, all sorts of trial and errors, etc...  I realize that I have to be doing something wrong/not seeing something but I just cannot seem to get it.

I am using XAMPP v3.2.1 (according to the Control Panel) on a Windows 8.1 machine.  This is just used for development/learning as XAMPP is intended.  I am just trying to get this working to make sure my scripts are running fine.  Everything seems to be working but I am just not receiving any e-mails from my script, which is just a simple mail script to test and see if it is working -

```
<?php

  mail("myid@yahoo.com", "Sample Mail", "Sample Content", "From:myid@gmail.com");

?>
```

Here is my code for the php.ini file -

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP=gmail.com
smtp_port=587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from=myid@gmail.com

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"`
```

And here is my code from the sendmail.ini file -

```
[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

default_domain=gmail.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=myid@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=myid@gmail.com

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=gmail.com`
```

If I have left anything out or if any other information is needed, please let me know as I am happy to provide it.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: From this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524464/cant-send-mails-from-xampp-localhost?rq=1): "You will need an additional SMTP Server Application because Xampp doesn't support it."

Comment: Use PHPMailer to connect to your gmail-smtp: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer (quite easy to configure and works perfectly fine)

Comment: Okay, thanks guys.  I thought that's what connecting to the gmail SMTP part of the ini file did?  Bypasses the need for a local mail server.  No?

Comment: Well, it is not something in the configuration but somewhere either on my side or Gmail's side.  I came back later and there was one of my e-mails in my inbox but it was delayed because I hasn't sent one for quite a while before the time stamp it was received on.  And it was only 1 e-mail, meaning there were quite a few that still didn't get delivered.  Does anyone know of any issues either with Gmail or my side that could be delaying and/or preventing the e-mails form being delivered?

Comment: Well, I ran a telnet test and if I connect through 587, then it does connect to Gmail.  So, if I am connecting to Gmail but it is still not being sent, then what might be the problem?

Comment: Even the sendmail debug file says that it is connecting to the Gmail smtp server but my script keeps saying the delivery failed and of course, the e-mail is still not delivered.

Comment: Okay, well I just got it working with Mercury so all is well.